# Undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::createView()

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I get the error :

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::createView()
```

For the following code

```
public function searchAction(Request $request, $type) {

    $filters = new Filters();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($filters)
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('project_search'))
        ->add('name', 'text');

    if($type == 'extra') {
        $form->add('job', 'text');
    }


    $form->add('send', 'submit', array('label' => "Envoyer"))
        ->getForm();


    return $this->render('Bundle:Controller:search.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I believe it is because I add a new input `$form->add('job', 'text');`. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reference to `Form` instance, not `FormBuilder`. You're already using `getForm()` method which returns needed reference, but you're not assiging it anywhere.

```
$filters = new Filters();

$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($filters)
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('project_search'))
    ->add('name', 'text');

if($type == 'extra') {
    $formBuilder->add('job', 'text');
}


$formBuilder->add('send', 'submit', array('label' => "Envoyer"));
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();


return $this->render('Bundle:Controller:search.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```